# Angular router fails to find parameters in url?

Tags: angular, typescript

> I have already tried the solutions from various other Stack Overflow
>   pages and Github pages and none seem to have worked.

**The problem:**

Angular router failing to find query string parameters in url even though the url contains the query string parameters.

`import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";`

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
    console.log(params["id_token"]);
  })
}`
```

Prints undefined to the console even though the query string parameter *id_token* is present in the url.

`const queryParams: URLSearchParams=(new URL(document.location.href)).searchParams;
console.log(queryParams);`

Prints the parameter *id_token* to the console.

Additionally I have also tried:

`import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";`

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe( params => {
    console.log(params["id_token"]);
  })
}`
```

Still undefined.

Also tried:

`console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id_token"));`

prints **null** not **undefined**

So I don't understand why the route.params or route.queryParams won't work?

Comment: What is your route definition? What is the actual URL you see in the browser?

Comment: webstie.com/home;page=1?id_token="aibjasdfadsfc...."

Comment: Add this to the question. `id_token` is actually a query string parameter rather than path parameter and that's why you won't be able to get it the way you do.

Comment: so trying something like `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(...`?

Comment: Perhaps try `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id_token')`

Comment: Yes. However the `/home;page=1` part seems a bit strange to me. Why do you need that `;`?

Comment: @Und3rTow I have tried that too, however the result is not undefined, instead it is null.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev `;` is for path parameter and `?` is for query string parameters?

Comment: Path parameters are separated by `/` (forward slash) in the Angular Router.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev when using `[routerLink]="['/details', {id:row.shift_id}]"` it separates the parameters with `;` but when using `[routerLink]="['/details']" [queryParams]="{id:row.shift_id}"` it separates the parameters with `?` have changed it to be using `?` now.

Comment: @Evan, the first example is wrong - it won't set `id` as a route param. You should use `[routerLink]="['/details', row.shift_id]"` or `routerLink="details/{{ row.shift_id }}"`